# How to interpret coefficient of continuous predictor in logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients

I have the following logistic regression in R:

```
glm(FundingSuccess ~ FundingGoal+ VentureTeamDiversity, 
      data = df, family = "binomial")
```

The `VentureTeamDiversity` variable is a Blau diversity index that ranges from 0 to 1. The regression coefficient of `VentureTeamDiversity` is 4.75 (p < 0.01). How do I interpret this coefficient? Basically, I am looking at understanding how much does an increase in `VentureTeamDiversity` by 10 percent affect the probability of successful funding (holding `FundingGoal` constant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coefficient $\beta_1$ can be interpreted as follows: $e^{\beta_1t}$ is the ratio of the odds of predicting a 1 after increasing $X_1$ by $t$ units to the odds of predicting a 1 while leaving $X_1$ alone.

In your specific scenario, $e^{4.75(0.10)} = 1.049$ means that the odds of getting funding after a 10% increase in VentureTeamDiversity is $1.049$ times the odds of getting funding without that increase.

There's also this answer [How to interpret logistic regression coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186748/how-to-interpret-logistic-regression-coefficient), which describes how to compute actual changes in the probability of predicting a 1, but that can only be computed at specific values of the predictor.

Comment: You could take the individual marginal effects at the observed values of $x$ and take the average over the estimation sample. This would produce a single number that gives you the average change in the probability of success associated with one additional unit of $x$ for everyone in the sample.